# update a random row from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this code here:

```
    UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = -1 WHERE (
SELECT starinformation.starID
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
)
```

I want to update a random row from a table with information pulled from that table and only effect 1 row.

Comment: `UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = -1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` would (very inefficiently) accomplish what you want.  But ***why*** anyone would ever want to do something like this is quite beyond me: it rather suggests very poor database design.

Comment: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: @Eggyal that doesn't work. and it's being used as part of a game i'm working on.

Comment: @user3462020: Er, [it does work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27522/1/0).  And "*part of a game i'm working on*" is insufficient information both for anyone to point out why your design is poor and for anyone to suggest a better design.

Comment: @Leo: Yeurgh! Quassnoi's blog article, [Selecting random rows](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/), offers a much better solution.

Comment: @eggyal actually I never knew choosing a random row was even possible using just proprietary sql ;-) sounds awkward

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with this approach:

- MySQL does not allow combining a modifying outer query with a selecting subquery to touch the same table
- `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` is a major performance killer: It will create an intermediate result of ALL rows - i.e. if your table contains 1 megarows, you will touch every single one of them.

My recommendation is to

- allways have a sortable single-field PK
- Run `SELECT ROUND(RAND()*COUNT(*)) AS num FROM starinformation`, returning $num
- Run `UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = -1 ORDER BY [pk-field] LIMIT $num,1`